# What is the difference between use of , (comma) and use of | (pipe) in 'except' xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

```
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node() except ($Abbr, $PrPostNum, $DocType, $DocSize)"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node() except ($Abbr | $PrPostNum | $DocType | $DocSize)"/>
```

Want to know the difference between above......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference. In both cases, all the nodes in `$Abbr`, `$pRPostNum`, etc are eliminated from the set of nodes selected by `node()`. The only difference is that with the union operator `|`, duplicates in the right-hand side of `except()` are eliminated first, but such duplicates have no effect on the final result so it doesn't matter whether you do this or not -- except possibly in terms of performance (which, of course, depends entirely on the implementation).